# Neo4j Aura demo python AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'execute_write'

Tags: python, neo4j-aura

In the Aura Python connection code, I have an issue with getting
attributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'execute_write' / 'execute_read' in

line 17    result = session.execute_write
line 44    result = session.execute_read

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this by replacing the

`execute_write` with `write_transaction`
`execute_read` with `read_transaction`

```
result = session.write_transaction(
result = session.read_transaction(
```